# Spring Integration Http Inbound Gateway Sending blank json reply

Tags: java, spring-integration

***Below code using Spring integration 2.2.6***

I want to send the response back to inbound gateway via reply channel. I am sending reply from service activator. But Spring is not able to set the response instead returning empty message

**Spring-Integration xml Config**

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="entryHttpInboundGateway"
        request-channel="entryInputChannel" path="/service/getSE/{uuid}" reply-channel="entryInboundReplyChannel"
        request-payload-type="com.test.ServiceEvent" mapped-response-headers="eventUUID, HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS"
        supported-methods="GET, POST"  reply-timeout="1000" view-name="/process/plain2">
        <int-http:header name="eventUUID" expression="#pathVariables.uuid"/>
 </int-http:inbound-gateway>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver" p:order="1" 
        p:defaultContentType="application/json">
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>

<int:service-activator id="sv2" input-channel="entryInputChannel" output-channel="outputChannel"
    method="sendReply" requires-reply="true" ref="checkService">
  </int:service-activator>

 <bean id="checkService" class="com.test.CheckService" />
```

**Posting the message to inbound adapter reply channel** **(com.test.CheckService.java)**

```
// Preparing the message to be sent to reply channel
     InboundReplyResponse inboundReplyResponse = new InboundReplyResponse();
        inboundReplyResponse.setMessage("Success");
        inboundReplyResponse.setEventUUID("12345");

    Map<String, Object> responseHeaderMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    responseHeaderMap.put("eventUUID",eventUUID);
                    responseHeaderMap.put("Content-Type","application/json");

    GenericMessage<InboundReplyResponse> message = new GenericMessage<InboundReplyResponse>(inboundReplyResponse,responseHeaderMap);


    //Reply queue -> entryInboundReplyChannel
        MessageChannel entryInboundReplyChannel =  (MessageChannel) AppFactory.getApplicationContext().getBean("entryInboundReplyChannel");

    entryInboundReplyChannel.send(message);
```

**web.xml**

```
 <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-integration-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ssTesting</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>    
        <servlet-name>ssTesting</servlet-name>    
        <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**Response returned to client**

```
<Empty JSON content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks bad.

You can send to that `entryInboundReplyChannel` directly, only if you are within the gateway's invocation thread. Because gateway's `sendAndReceive` relies on `TemporaryReplyChannel` in the `MessageHeaders`. And that last one is involved independently of explicit `reply-channel` on the `inbound-gateway`.

Why just don't use `entryInboundReplyChannel` as `output-channel` for the `<service-activator>` and just return the message from `sendReply` method and just rely on Framewrok abilities to midiate flow correctly?

I meand don't use `entryInboundReplyChannel.send(message)` manually.

Comment: thanks Artem for your response. I want to reply back to the client via reply channel immediately with "uuid" as when I receive the request. I do not want to wait for my whole processing to complete and then sending back the reply. Therefore sending the reply back by using entryInboundReplyChannel.send(message). As referred by you to use <service-activator> outbound channel as reply channel, the outbound channel is configured as input to router for further processing. Therefore I had to write the send code manually in the service activator which has input-channel of request-channel.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

```
// Instead of creating a new header, Request Message header should be used  

public  Message<ServiceMsg> (Message<?> inMessage){
....
....
GenericMessage<InboundReplyResponse> message = new GenericMessage<InboundReplyResponse>(inboundReplyResponse,inMessage.getHeaders());
```